# New Variable Based on Previous Observation

Tags: r, lubridate

I have sleep data that includes one field for the time my son went to bed and another field for what time he woke up. I want to create a new variable that calculates total time spent asleep. In other words I need the difference between wake time for each day and bed time ON THE PREVIOUS DAY.

```
library(lubridate)

day <- mdy("8/27/19","8/28/19","8/29/19")
wake <- hms("7:35:00","7:45:00","7:30:00")
bed <- hms("19:45:00","20:15:00","20:00:00")
toy_data <- tibble(day, wake, bed)
```

I tried doing this with a loop:

```
toy_data$sleeptime <- NA

for(i in 1:nrow(toy_data)){
  toy_data$sleeptime[i] <- as.duration(toy_data$bed[i-1] - toy_data$wake[i])
}
```

but get an error:

```
replacement has length zero
```

Comment: There are a few problems here, but one is that you're trying to access index 0...

Comment: Correct. I wanted to give an example of what I tried and wasn't sure how else to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
toy_data %>%
  mutate(sleep_time = as.duration(wake) - lag(as.duration(bed)) + dhours(24))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  day        wake         bed          sleep_time           
  <date>     <S4: Period> <S4: Period> <S4: Duration>       
1 2019-08-27 7H 35M 0S    19H 45M 0S   NA                   
2 2019-08-28 7H 45M 0S    20H 15M 0S   43200s (~12 hours)   
3 2019-08-29 7H 30M 0S    20H 0M 0S    40500s (~11.25 hours)
```

I wasn't having luck getting the `lag` of the original columns in `S4: Period` form, but it worked when I did the calculation between two durations.

Answer (score 1):

```
ind = match(toy_data$day - 1, toy_data$day)
as.numeric(ymd_hms(paste(toy_data$day, toy_data$wake)) - 
               ymd_hms(paste(toy_data$day[ind], toy_data$bed[ind])))
#[1]    NA 12.00 11.25
#Warning message:
# 1 failed to parse.
```

Answer (score 1):

One option that might make things more simple would be to pass in strings rather than `mdy` and `hms` objects, which makes it easy to turn each column into a full date object that is easily manipulated:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

day <- c("8/27/19","8/28/19","8/29/19")
wake <- c("7:35:00","7:45:00","7:30:00")
bed <- c("19:45:00","20:15:00","20:00:00")
toy_data <- tibble(day, wake, bed)

toy_data %>% 
  mutate(
    wake = mdy_hms(str_c(day, wake, sep = " ")),
    bed = mdy_hms(str_c(day, bed, sep = " ")),
    sleep = lead(wake) - bed
  )

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  day     wake                bed                 sleep      
  <chr>   <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>     
1 8/27/19 2019-08-27 07:35:00 2019-08-27 19:45:00 12.00 hours
2 8/28/19 2019-08-28 07:45:00 2019-08-28 20:15:00 11.25 hours
3 8/29/19 2019-08-29 07:30:00 2019-08-29 20:00:00    NA hours
```

Then you can use `lead` to access the wake time from the next day, or make the small alteration to `lag` if you want the sleep time to show up on the following day.